# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey on Java servlet

Tags: servlets, unknown-host

There are other similar questions to this, but I don't feel like it answers mine. From a Java servlet I need to be able to ssh to any server on my company's network and dynamically handle this unknown key exception and then issue a command to get and display the current status of the server.

I saw one suggestion to use JSch session.setFingerprint, but it must have changed or something because far as I can tell, it doesn't exist. I'm using Netbeans.

Here's my code:

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String url = "validurl";
String user = "validuser";
String password = "validpassword";
printer.println ("HelloWorld!");

JSch ssh = new JSch();
ChannelShell ch = null;
Session session = null;
try {
  session = ssh.getSession(user, "serverIP", 22);
  session.setPassword(password);
  session.connect();

  ch = (ChannelShell)session.openChannel("shell");
  ch.connect();
}
catch (JSchException e) {
  System.out.println ("Exception: " + e);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println ("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Thanks!
Devin